# 301 Redirect the Out of Stock Product Pages

Tags: magento2, redirect, magento2.2.2, out-of-stock, 301-redirect

Want to redirect for the products who are out of stock to custom url

Had tried below url but it did not helped
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824072/magento-out-of-stock-product-seo-problem

Comment: 301 is permanent redirect. What would seo benefit of doing this instead of using status or visibility to show a 404? I can understand 302 in case comes back in  stock? Or are these discontinued products?

Comment: No they are not discontinued just stock has got over. But in future, there can be such a case where the product can be discontinued

Comment: In that case do you still want to use 301's?

Comment: But how to do it. That's my question how to redirect to custom url with 301/302 when there is no stock

Answer (score 0):

You need to overide this method

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Product/View.php#L78

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/86501/70343

Check stock with something like this

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/97952/70343

Then redirect using something like this

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/177876/70343